# Add new column in file using sed

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I am trying to add a new column in a file and using below command got from another Stack overflow post:

```
sed "s/$col/$col$FSEP$value/" $file > ${file%.*}"_m.txt"
```

`col=1` is column number, `value=20171231` is the  and `FSEP=|` is the field seperator.

current data:

```
"01    "|"name "|"address "|" phone number"
```

current output:

```
"01|20171231    "|"name "|"address "|" phone number"
```

expected output:

```
"01" |"20171231    "|"name "|"address "|" phone number"
```

The `sed` is not considering double quotes well. How can I achieve that?

Comment: not clear, are you "setting" col1 with `$col1=1`? It should be a seperate line of code, like `col=1`. Then you reference it with `$1`, but you'll really need `col1='"01     "'` to match the values up to the first `|` char. (tweak that assignment to match your requirements). You know `awk` is designed to process records by any char defined as a `FS`, and then reference fields as `$1, $2, .... $n` ? This would be much easier using `awk`. See the awk tutorial at https://gryimore.com/Unix/Awk.html. Good luck.

Comment: Also, you haven't explaned the change to that initial `col1` value, from `"01    "` to `"01" ` (with a trailing space char). Is that a typo, if so, please fix your original Q or explain the change in the body of your Q. Good luck.

Comment: So I think I have phrased the question wrongly, I am not setting `$col=1` I meant to say value of col is 1 and same for other variables.

Comment: The link that you pasted does not work but I am looking into `awk` right now and looks like its much more easier to use, I will look it and try to come up with solution, if you have one you can paste. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry about the bad link, normally I test it after it type it. Glad you found it anyway. (For other readers, it is [awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html). Will think about your problem. Please update your Q to address issues in my 2nd comment. Good luck.

Comment: `echo '"01    "|"name "|"address "|" phone number"' | awk '-F|' '{$1=$1"  |\"20171231 \"|"; sub(/  */,"",$1);print}'` is pretty close, but don't want to spend more time on this  until I know for certain your specified output is correctly stated in your Q. Good luck.